# Is there a way to track changes made in each work item? Like the data that's available on the History section

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to write a Python function that returns all the changes made to one or more fields of any Azure DevOps work item. My end goal is to have the function return this data in JSON format, so that then I can parse it to a CSV file for reporting purposes.

I've spent all day today learning how to work with the Azure DevOps REST API and finally got to the point where my requests are working (200 OK). I'm a beginner with APIs if you haven't noticed by now.

I managed to write a function that returns a list of a work item's current values based on a WIQL query I give it. I'm just not familiar with which API entity set I should use to look into work item changes, specifically to the changes a field receives, for example changing a Title, or WorkItemType. Hopefully I can get this question answered here!

Answer (score 2):

The REST API does have endpoints for querying work-item revisions.

- [Work-Item Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP): If you know the work-items you're after, you can get the revision history for each individual work-item. This is equivalent to the History tab on the work-item.
- [Reporting Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/reporting-work-item-revisions?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1): If you want to collect all changes in a project from a particular time forward, you can use this endpoint to retrieve and paginate through all changes.

  - This endpoint has a `fields` attribute that can be used to specify which fields to return, which may prove to be useful if you're only after a specific-field.
  - If you don't specify the `startDateTime` attribute, you'll start at the beginning.
  - The result includes a `isLastBatch` which indicates if it's the last paginated batch of data. It also includes a handy `nextLink` which is the URL to the next set of data.

In PowerShell, it would something along these lines:

```bash
# define your secrets and salt to taste
$AccessToken = "<YOUR-PAT>"
$OrganizationName = "<YOUR-ORG>"
$ProjectName = "<YOUR-PROJECT>"

$header = @{ 
  Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AccessToken)"))
}

# Define your Project URL
$uri  = "https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/$ProjectName"

# Tack on the REST API Endpoint
$uri += "/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?api-version=7.1-preview.2"

# append the fields you're interested in
$uri += "&fields=System.Title,System.Description"

# add the date to start processing from
$uri += "&startDateTime=2023/01/31"

# make the URL friendly, in case you have spaces in your project name...
$uri = [Uri]::EscapeUriString($uri)

# create an array to hold your changes
$changes = @() 

# set a flag to know if we're done fetching the results...
$done = $false

# fetch and loop until we're done!
while(-not $done) {
   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Method GET
   if ($result) {
      $changes += $result.values
   }
   $done = $result.IsLastBatch
   $uri = $result.nextLink
}

# Invoke-RestMethod will convert the JSON data into an object, so if you
# want to drop it back into JSON we can do that here...
$changes | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Alternatively, there is also a Webhook for "[WorkItem Updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops#work-item-updated)" that could also be used to get real-time updates to work-items in your projects.